# how to change type of value in an php array and sorting it..is it possible?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i got problem with my code and hopefully someone able to figure it out. The main purpose is **to sort array based on its value (then reindex its numerical key)**.

i got this sample of filename :

```
  $filename = array("index 198.php", "index 192.php", "index 144.php", "index 2.php",  "index 1.php", "index 100.php", "index 111.php");

  $alloutput = array(); //all of index in array

  foreach ($filename as $name) {
    preg_match('#(\d+)#', $name, $output);      // take only the numerical from file name 
    array_shift($output);                       // cleaned. the last code create duplicate numerical in $output, 
    if (is_array($output)) {
        $alloutput = array_merge($alloutput, $output);
    }
  }


//try to check the type of every value in array
foreach ($alloutput as $output) { 
    if (is_array($output)) {
        echo "array true </br>";        
    } elseif (is_int($output)) {
        echo "integer true </br>";
    } elseif (is_string($output)) {   //the numerical taken from filename always resuld "string". 
        echo "string true </br>";
    }   
}
```

the output of this code will be :

Array
(
    [0] => 198
    [1] => 192
    [2] => 144
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 100
    [6] => 111
)

i have test every output in array. **It's all string (and not numerical)**, So the question is how to change this string to integer, so **i can sort it from the lowest into the highest number**  ?

the main purpose of this code is how to output array where it had been sort from lowest to highest ?

Comment: I don't understand your code, there are undefined vars in your loops (hasil and hasilku)

Comment: nicolo, i'm very sorry with that. i will try to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match` will keep the matched part in `$outpu[1]`, so you can make use of that to convert the `string` to `int` and then add it to your `alloutput` array.

```
foreach ($filename as $name) {
    preg_match('#(\d+)#', $name, $output);
    $alloutput[] = intval($output[1]);
}
```

Comment: it's you again...lol Thanks i will try to find the way to sort it ;D

Comment: sorry i use the wrong code in the above code. but i understand your answer  ;D

Comment: @justjoe: To sort you can use the sort function. Also you need not have to convert the strings to int before you sort. The sort function takes an argument SORT_NUMERIC. Which will treat your array elements are numeric. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$number_string = '14';
$number = intval('14');
```

With intval you can specify also the basis. If the number is decimal, hower, you can also use

```
$number = (int) $number_string;
```

Comment: i know about this. but i hope the solution given in the first foreach. so it will be more directly.sorry if it's too much